# Passing Struct elements of variable lengths into a matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

I am parshing a few data via the internet. The struct `Data` has several elements. I am interested in `Data.Value` a call of `Data(1,1).Value` is a double vector of [56,1]. Moving on to the second struct cell `Data(1,2).Value` is a double vector [46,1].

Writing a FOR Loop to get the entire `Data(1,i).Value` from 1 to 500, when it come to the second element, I get the following error returned: `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`

Although I understand the error I cannot justify it and hence I cannot work out a solution.

I have also tried to pre-define a matrix of variable sizes to overcome this, without result.

Anybody can think of any solution to get the entire `Data(1,:).Value`

Thanks a lot for the contribution guys.

Comment: can you show the part of the code that does want you are explaining?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
vertcat(Data(1,:).Value)
```

to create a column vector made by concatenating `Data(1,1).Value`, `Data(1,2).Value`, ...
Alternatively, you can use the generalized concatenation operator

```
cat(1, Data(1,:).Value)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the interest guys. Great commands to know. While applying `vertcat(Data(1,:).Value)` I can get the all of the struct contentes into a single vector, when it comes to distributing struct elements `Data(1,i).Value` to a single matrix, I still get the same error due to the fact that different struct elements have different lengths. Could it be that what I am trying to achieve is impossible under Matlab?